# jQuery Value set with variables oddly not working

Tags: php, jquery, variables

The following code

```
function calendar(datadate) {

    var data = $(datadate).val();

    $('#cal_startdate').val(data);  
}
```

Is called in this way

```
onclick="calendar('CAL01V');
```

Yet is not working. I must of missed something but my mind has clayed like an 18th century china pot right now. Perhaps one of you could provide assistance.

Marvellous

Comment: What is `CAL01V`? You're passing that into your function as a string.

Comment: Why are you using the onclick attribute? You could just bind the click handler via jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you passing just a `string literal` into `calendar()` on your `onclick` handler.

```
$(datedate)
```

calls the jQuery constructor with that string ("CAL01V"), which is not gonna work. You should just skip the part and directly pass the argument into the `.val()` method:

```
function calendar(datadate) {
    $('#cal_startdate').val(datadate);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You click on the element that have 'onclick' event binded, and the function calendar is called like this:

```
function calendar('CAL01V'){
  var data = $('CAL01V').val();
  $('#cal_startdate').val(data);  
}
```

And you don't have any element with this tag name, so the function isn't going to work.

Probably, you need to add something like this (notice '#'):

```
function calendar(datadate) {
  var data = $('#'+datadate).val();   // To look for using element's ID
  $('#cal_startdate').val(data);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="calendar('#CAL01V');
```

whoops